# The kernel of all invariant means

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, amenability

Let $G$ be a discrete group which is amenable (i.e. it admits an left-invariant mean, i.e. a continuous positive normalised linear functional $m:\ell^\infty(G) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall g \in G, m \circ \lambda_g = m$ where $\lambda_g : \ell^\infty(G) \to \ell^\infty(G)$ is the left-regular action of $G$). Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of all invariant means on $G$.

Let $c_0(G)$ be the space of bounded functions decreasing to $0$ at $\infty$ (i.e. $f \in c_0(G)$ if $f$ is in the closure of the space of finitely supported functions, i.e. $f \in \ell^\infty(G)$ and $\forall \epsilon >0$ there exists a finite set $F \subset G$ with $\lVert f\rVert_{\ell^\infty(G \setminus F)} \leq \epsilon$).

It's not difficult to see that $c_0(G)$ is included in the kernel of all (left- or right- or bi-)invariant mean, provided $G$ is infinite. When $G$ is finite, there is only one such mean, and it is trivial to compute the kernel. However the cardinality of $\mathcal{M}$ is otherwise quite big (if I remember correctly, it is uncountable for $G=\mathbb{Z}$).

**Question**: Assuming $G$ is infinite, is there a description/characterisation of the elements of $\ell^\infty(G)$ which belong to the kernel of all the invariant means, i.e. $\bigcap_{m \in \mathcal{M}} \ker m$?

Comment: The trivial answer would be the closed linear span of $\lbrace f-\lambda_g(f) : g \in G,\ f\in\ell_\infty G\rbrace$.

Comment: Did you compute it for $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Is this MO question useful to you? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/65325/intrinsically-measurable-subsets-of-amenable-semigroups

Comment: @Mark: I'm not sure if this is explicit enough, but
take any Folner sequence $F_n$. Then, $f$ has mean zero iff 
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in G}|\sum_{y\in F_nx}f(y)|/|F_n|=0$. $\because$ If it's nonzero, then the uniform measure on $F_nx_n$ tends to an invariant mean which is nonzero at $f$. The converse follows from the fact that $f_n(x):=\sum_{y\in F_nx}f(y)/|F_n|$ has the same mean as $f$.

Comment: @Narutaka: Your answer is good enough for me. I do not know about Antoine. 

Comment: Thanks for the comments and references, it makes a good enough answer for me too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Essentially from Narutaka Ozawa's comments)

Let $K = \bigcap_{m \in \mathcal{M}} \ker m$. The trivial answer would be that $K$ is the closed linear span of
$$S =\{f-\lambda_g(f):\;g\in G,\;f\in\ell^\infty(G) \}.$$

For a non-amenable group this is all of $\ell^\infty(G)$. For an amenable group with Følner net $(F_i)$, then for any $f \in K$
$$\lim_{i\to\infty}\sup_{x\in G}\frac{\left|\sum_{y\in F_ix}f(y)\right|}{|F_i|}=0.$$
Indeed, if it's nonzero, we can find $(x_i)$ such that
$$\limsup\frac{\left|\sum_{y\in F_ix_i}f(y)\right|}{|F_i|}>0;$$
then the uniform measure on $F_ix_i$ accumulates to an invariant mean that is non-zero at $f$.

Hence, if $f \in K$, then
$$f_i(x)=\sum_{y\in F_ix}\frac{f(y)}{|F_i|}$$
has the same mean as $f$ for every invariant mean. A consequence of the above is that $\|f_i\|_{\ell^\infty} \to 0$. Thus $f - f_i \in S$ and $f-f_i \to f$ which shows that $K \subset \overline{S}$.

The inclusion $\overline{S} \subset K$ is a direct consequence of the invariance of the mean.

Comment: I made quite a big edit, please feel free to roll back if I messed it up. Reading this proof after a few year, the crucial point that elements of $K$ are limits of elements of $S$ was hard to understand.

Comment: @ARG it's fine; just prefer $\bigcap$ (bigcap) for multiple intersections to $\cap$ (cap) which is only for intersections as binary operator.

Comment: ah, sorry... I usually use \displaystyle (which normally turns the $\cap$ into $\bigcap$ automatically) but forgot to do it here

Comment: @ARG, `\displaystyle` doesn't convert $\cap$ `\cap` to $\bigcap$ `\bigcap`; see $\cap\bigcap\displaystyle\cap\bigcap$ `\cap\bigcap\displaystyle\cap\bigcap`.  You always need to use it manually when appropriate.

Comment: Sorry for the foolish question, but why is it obvious that the trivial answer gives the full kernel?  It is obvious that it is contained in the kernel, but why is it obvious that there are enough invariant means that nothing outside the span you indicate is annihilated by all of them?

Comment: @Lspice oh! cool, thanks for the latex-info! As for the math: it is not trivial to me! (that's most of the content of the answer). (1) any element of the kernel satisfies (*) (the equation with $\displaystyle \lim_{i \to \infty} \sup_{x \in G} ... =0$) (2) so do the $f_i$ (because they also have 0 mean. (3) $f-f_i \in S$ (it's a convex combination of some $f - \lambda_g f$) (4) because of (2), the $f-f_i$ tend to $f$ (for this you have to interpret (2) as saying that the $f_i \to 0$ in norm). (5) this is how you show $K$ is contained in the closure of $S$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in this paper: *Yuji Takahashi, Functions with a unique mean value and amenability. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 121 (1994), 775-777*   ([Freely accessible here on AMS' site](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1994-121-03/S0002-9939-1994-1189549-1/home.html))

Comment: Actually, Yuji Takahashi only cites the Theorem 1.1 (and proves something nice in the context) in [Rosenblatt and Yang](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-34/issue-4/Functions-with-a-unique-mean-value/10.1215/ijm/1255988066.full) which essentially answers the question. (There it is formulated as a result on functions which always have the same means, so you have to consider the constant function.) The Paper of Rosenblatt and Yang is also freely availiable.

Comment: @ARG, to protect against re-organisations of journal sites (Springer is a particularly bad offender, for example), it is often good to link to the DOI when possible:  [Rosenblatt and Yang - Functions with a unique mean value](https://doi.org/10.1215/ijm/1255988066).